# Change Views when UIAlertView Button is clicked

Tags: uitableview, ios6, hyperlink, uialertview

I have a quiz program that starts with a TableView and then moves to a second View as the quiz is selected. In this second view there is a Nav bar at the top with a back button that takes you back to the tableView. I'd like to accomplish this same action when the user clicks a button on a UIAlertView that displays their final score at the end of each quiz. Can anyone help me with this, or direct me to a tutorial? This is my first multi view app.

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
NSString *buttonTitle = [alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];
if (alertView.tag == 5) {
    if ([buttonTitle isEqualToString:@"Main Menu"]) {
        KHQuizViewController *vc = [[KHQuizViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"KHViewController" bundle:nil];

        [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
        [vc release];
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You need to submit some of the code you've tried so far to give us a starting point.  Thanks!

Comment: I added the code to my original post. This is what I tried because it seems that the code between lines 5 and 8 are what pushed the code to this view, so I was trying to use it (and just change the initWithNibName: to the first view) to push it back, but it breaks the program.

Comment: I think you just need to pop view controllers from the navigation controller's stack until you end up back at the main menu. Creating a new main menu instance is not going to end well.

Comment: How would I POP view controllers from the navigation contoller's stack?

Comment: I'm looking it up right now.  Hope to have the answer for you soon or I'll be late for dinner on Valentine's Day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of trying to push a new instance of your main menu, just pop back to the root view with this line:

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES]
```

This information is provided by the [Apple IOS Developer Library here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UINavigationController).

In the context of your `alertView` selector:

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    NSString *buttonTitle = [alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];
    if (alertView.tag == 5) {
        if ([buttonTitle isEqualToString:@"Main Menu"]) {
            [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];        
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The program is still breaking. Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you be more specific? Is it crashing or doing nothing at all? If we add a call to `NSLog()` inside the `if` statement, does that print to the debug console?

Comment: It's working! Does anybody know why when I have a break code and i remove that line of code, the program will continue to crash? I had to create a new project and copy all the code over to get it to work.

Comment: I have no clue. Which iOS version are you targeting? Which version of xcode do you use?

Comment: targeting 6.0 iPhone, using Xcode 4.5.2. It's just odd. I removed everything within the 'if' statement and added a NSLog to make sure the loop was completing, then stopped all tasks and rebuilt, but the simulator would still exit out and give me a breakpoint. This isn't the first project that I've had this issue on either.

Comment: You should write that up as a unique question and see if anyone else on this site has run into that.